# Non-Abelian group with identity 1

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

My question is the following:

Is there a non-Abelian group with identity element 1? And if there is/isn't, how to prove it?

Edited to add the reasoning behind my question. I think I can show that if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are subgroups of a group $G$ with $H_1\cap H_2=\{1\}$ and $h_1h_2=1$ ($h_1 \in H_1, h_2\in H_2)$, then $h_1=h_2=1$ without using the fact that $G$ is Abelian. My course text includes the condition for $G$ to be Abelian (and then says that this is an interesting fact about Abelian groups). So I'm trying to see whether including that condition is trivial or not (i.e. if the conditions above hold, the group is automatically Abelian).

Comment: For a multiplicative group, abelian or not, unless another name is standard for the given group, the identity element is typically named "1". So your question is unclear.

Comment: So can you think of a non-Abelian group for which the conditions in my edit hold?

Comment: When you edited the question you should have deleted the part about nonabelian groups with identity $1$, which does not make sense.

Comment: Within my frame of reference it did/does make sense, since that's what the question was about. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: The point is that you can call the identity element of any group anything you like. You could call it "orange" or $1000000$ or $S_5$.

Comment: As indicated in comments below, the OP isn't looking to take an arbitrary non-Abelian group and call its identity "$1$", but for an example of the familiar integer $1$ playing the role of identity in a non-Abelian group, in some non-contrived way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a famous group that furnishes an example of a non-Abelian group whose identity is something that we would readily recognize as identifying with the real number $1$, namely the [quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group). It is often written as $\{\pm 1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$, and its operation is defined by the relations $i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$. It is a subset of an extension of $\mathbb C$ called the [Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion), which is another good example for you.

The condition you're talking about is true for any group, Abelian or not. From $h_1h_2=1$, we have that $h_2=h_1^{-1}$, and the subgroup $H_1$ is closed under inverses, so $h_2\in H_1\cap H_2$. We can argue the same for $h_1$.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't encountered quaternions in my studies before, what would you say are the prerequisites to start understanding them? At what level are they normally studied (would an undergraduate study them?)

Comment: If you're studying group theory, there's no reason not to look at quaternoins as an example. They have an interesting history, as they originally arose as an alternative to matrices for describing rotations (and other geometry) in 3 dimensions. Because matrices became standard, quaternions are often neglected in the standard course of study. I've probably heard the most about them in the context of finite group theory - they provide a non-Abelian group of order 8 that isn't $D_4$, and the comparison of $D_4$ with $Q_8$ is instructive. For example, $Q_8$ has no non-normal subgroups!

Comment: That's very interesting. I'll definitely look into them, especially for the comparison with $D_4$ that you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your original question . . .

The identity element of any group can be labeled as the symbol $1$.

Even the actual integer $1$ can be the identity element of a non-abelian group, provided the multiplication is defined appropriately.

For example, take the non-abelian group $S_3$, and relabel the elements as $1,2,3,4,5,6$, using $1$ as the identity element, and with multiplication defined so as to match the multiplication in $S_3$. Thus, the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ of $6$ integers, with the new multiplication rule, is a non-abelian group with the integer $1$ as the identity element.

I think that answers the original question.

The key point is that naming of elements is arbitrary. It's the multiplication rule that determines the nature of the group, not the symbols used to denote the elements.

As regards your edit . . .

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H_1,H_2$ be subgroups of $G$ such that $H_1 \cap H_2 = \{1\}$.

Suppose $h_1,h_2$ are such that $h_1\in H_1,\;h_2 \in H_2,\;$and$\;h_1h_2=1$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&h_1h_2=1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&h_1=h_2^{-1}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&h_1 \in H_2\\[4pt] 
\implies\;&h_1 = 1&&\text{[since $H_1 \cap H_2 = \{1\}$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&h_2 =1&&\text{[since $h_1h_2=1$]}\\[4pt] 
\end{align*}
Thus, the statement you described is true regardless of whether or not $G$ is abelian.

As an example to illutrate that the hypothesis is satisfiable for $G$ non-abelian, let $G = S_3$ and let $H_1,H_2$ be cyclic subgroups of $G$ of orders $2$ and $3$ respectively. Then $G$ is non-abelian, and $H_1,H_2$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $H_1 \cap H_2 = \{1\}$.

Comment: Yes, this is almost exactly how I proved it. I am still not sure how one would redefine the binary operation on $S_3$ in practice though. How would you define the new operation? Listing all the results separately? Would it be possible to find a general rule? For instance, we might need (to cite a few, for a certain relabelling) $2\times2=1,3\times3=1, 5\times6=1, 3\times4=6,4\times3=5  $. On another note, why does my question keep getting negative "marks"? Is it really that dumb? I'm trying to be critical of my course text and understanding underlying principles.

Comment: Using a multiplication table. Take the multiplication table for $S_3$ and relabel the elements as $1,2,3,4,5,6$, using the label $1$ for the identity element.

Comment: Yes. So perhaps my initial question should have been "in a natural way"? This isn't very rigorous, but I was trying to find a group where 1 is "naturally" the identity element of a binary operation. I'm not sure how else to express it, but that's what I had in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is, I guess, however you mean it, in particular whatever object your symbol $1$ is denoting.

Take any non-Abelian group (say, $S_3$), and modify its underlying set by replacing its original identity by your favorit object $1$. Define the group operation on this modestly modified underlying set so that $1$ acts as an identity, otherwise keep the original results.

Comment: I think I get what you mean, but it is somewhat difficult to get my head around it. $S_3$ is a permutation group, so the identity is $(1)(2)(3)=e$. The integer 1 is not a permutation, though I guess I could use it as a name for $e$. But I'm not sure it's still applicable in the context I mention in my edit.